# Visual Studio online solution sync error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am using VisualStudio online to sync my repository between my laptop and workstation, everytime I pull the updates from the repo to my laptop, I get this error "The name XXXX does not exist in the context" for all kinda folders. I don't know what the problem is, I have tried clean and rebuild, changing build configurations and ...

Comment: Git? Tfvc? Any error code or exception location?

Comment: Git, The name "XXXXX" does not exist in the context, for example , the code behind the xaml page doesn't see the controls,

Comment: All of my customControls are in a folder Controls Folder, but the I get this error that the name XXXXX doesn't exist in the namespace XXXX.Controls

Comment: To me it looks like the solution/project doesn't see this folders as source folders,

Comment: Do you get the error when do a git pull or when queue a build? Per my understanding you may get the error when you queue a build if your project can't find necessary files. Be sure that xxxx is included and checked in version control.

Comment: Looks like you gave untracked changes in your solution. Your workstation has 'm on disk but they are not part of the Git repo.

Comment: The repo was updated to the last push I had made, I reconfigured the solution from debug to release and clean and rebuilt it and it worked